# I can't make a foreach from an array in laravel 5.5 blade

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, foreach, laravel-blade

I can't make a foreach from an array in Laravel 5.5 blade

```
<select name={{$question->id}}>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    @foreach ((array) $question->response_choice as $key=>$value)
        <option value={{$value}}>{{$value}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

the $question->response_choice is : ["Not at all", "Less than 1 in 5 times","Less than half the time","About half the time","More than half the time","Almost always"]

and with this code i have a dropdown list with only one value
["Not at all", "Less than 1 in 5 times","Less than half the time","About half the time","More than half the time","Almost always"]

the same..

is a bug in laravel?

Comment: Where is the foreach and the array?

Comment: is in the code,, on the right if you move the slider,,, sorry i din't formated well the code

Comment: Ok! I edited that.

Comment: it's not strange? i don't know why is happend like this,,, i also tryied without $key=>$value, only with $value, because the array is not associative, he don't have keys

Comment: If you `dd($question->response_choice);` before sending this to the view, what does it print?

Comment: the dd is giving me: "["Not at all", "Less than 1 in 5 times","Less than half the time","About half the time","More than half the time","Almost always"]",,, soo he have " " in the front and in the end,, soo the blade is seeing this array like a string?

Comment: @DanManolache I think you make the array in the wrong way. show us the dd($question), by key and values.

Comment: dd($questions) is: Collection {#654 ▼
  #items: array:43 [▼
    0 => Questions {#655 ▶}
    1 => Questions {#656 ▶}
    2 => Questions {#657 ▶}
    3 => Questions {#658 ▶}
    4 => Questions {#659 ▶}
    5 => Questions {#660 ▶}
    6 => Questions {#661 ▶}
    7 => Questions {#662 ▶}
    8 => Questions {#663 ▶}
    9 => Questions {#664 ▶}
    10 => Questions {#665 ▶}
    11 => Questions {#666 ▶}
    12 => Questions {#667 ▶}
    13 => Questions {#668 ▶}

Comment: the problem is that the blade is seeing this array like a STRING...

Comment: @DanManolache the problem is when you dd the $question->response_choice it must show something like this: {"0:Not at all", "1:Less than 1 in 5 times","2:Less than half the time","3:About half the time","4:More than half the time","5:Almost always"} if its jsone or an array. i

Comment: @DanManolache but it shows it like a string. I think you must go back and check the column or controller, where you make that array.

Comment: yes, i solved the bug,, i transformed the string to an array,,, the problem is that the blade dosen't see an array to be an array ,, so you will need to do an explode

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `$question->response_choice` is json string, that's why you should use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) before iterating:

```
@foreach ( json_decode($question->response_choice, true) as $choice)
    <option>{{ $choice }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\www\htdocs\ihm\resources\views\patient\edit.blade.php)

Comment: Try this `$question->response_choice->toArray() as $choice`

Comment: Its a json you should use `json_decode($question->response_choice) as $choice`, I updated my answer

Comment: if i do $question->response_choice->toArray() : Call to a member function toArray() on string (View: C:\www\htdocs\ihm\resources\views\patient\edit.blade.php)

Comment: if i do json_decode($question->response_choice) as $choice, : nvalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\www\htdocs\ihm\resources\views\patient\edit.blade.php)

Comment: @YouneL Sry it was Unintentional. I was just writing it when you answer. I will delete it!

Comment: @DanManolache, Yes I was thinking that `response_choice` was a relation ship, try my updated answer

Comment: Please show the output of dd($questions->first()->response_choice);